# Select payment method onclick

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout

We use 3 payment methods and I want to select a payment method if the customer clicks on the li class.

We use this code:

```
<li class="formListBlock" onclick="$('p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>').checked=true;payment.switchMethod('<?php echo $_code ?>')"<?php if($this->getSelectedMethodCode()==$_code): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?>>
<?php if(!$oneMethod): ?>
    <input id="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>" value="<?php echo $_code ?>" type="radio" name="payment[method]" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_method->getTitle()) ?>" onclick="payment.switchMethod('<?php echo $_code ?>')"<?php if($this->getSelectedMethodCode()==$_code): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="radio" />
<?php else: ?>
    <span class="no-display"><input id="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>" value="<?php echo $_code ?>" type="radio" name="payment[method]" checked="checked" class="radio" /></span>
    <?php $oneMethod = $_code; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
    <label for="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getMethodTitle($_method)) ?> <?php echo $this->getMethodLabelAfterHtml($_method) ?><span class="gratis">Gratis</span></label>
<?php if ($html = $this->getPaymentMethodFormHtml($_method)): ?>
<span class="payment_icon_<?php echo $_code ?>"></span>
<div class="formListBlock-selector">
    <ul class="form-list ops-form-list" id="payment_form_ops_iDeal" style="display:none;">
<li>
    <select name="payment[iDeal_issuer_id]" id="ops_iDeal_issuer_id" class="required-entry">
    <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('--Please Select--')?></option>
        <?php foreach ($issuers as $key => $value): ?>
            <option value=<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($key) ?>>
                <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($value) ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</li>
    <button type="button" class="button" onclick="payment.save()"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue') ?></span></span></button>
</ul>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </li>
```

Error on Chrome console:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS

<script>(function() {with (this[2]) {with (this[1]) {with (this[0]) {return function(event) {$('p_method_ops_iDeal').checked=true;payment.switchMethod('ops_iDeal')
};}}}})</script>
```

How can I select the radio button by clicking the li and make it work on every browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<li class="control" onclick="$('p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>').checked=true;" <?php if($this->getSelectedMethodCode()==$_code): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> >
    <input id="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>" value="<?php echo $_code ?>" type="radio" name="payment[method]" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_method->getTitle()) ?>" onclick="payment.switchMethod('<?php echo $_code ?>')"<?php if($this->getSelectedMethodCode()==$_code): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="radio" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but that did not work. The underlaying span with the select box is does not load then. That's why we need the code  "payment.switchMethod". Is it possible to combine these two codes?

Comment: Try `onclick="$('p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>').checked=true;payment.switchMethod"`

Comment: Problem solved the issue on FireFox, but now the problem is that the underlaying select menulist in Chrome can't be selected. This automatically collapse back.

Same problem as we had before when we changed the li class to an label. That worked perfectly on Chrome and Safari, but not inFireFox.

How can we fix this issue?

Comment: can you update your question with current code? Also with the code above you dont need `<label>`

Comment: Did you check your JS error console?

Comment: I updated the code, see above.

Comment: Your original issue yesterday was to auto select the radio button when you click the li, is this still your current issue and are you using label tag?

Comment: The problem to auto select the radio button is working, but the underlaying li with the <select> class is not working. In Google Chrome the <select> menulist can not be opened, this auto close immediately. So this solution to the auto select radio button, causes a new problem with the <select> menu list. So we need to fix that also.

Comment: When you manually click on the radio to open the menu, do you have this issue?

Comment: Yes when I manually click on the radio, the same problem appears. But when I remove the onclick addition on the <li> the problem <select> works good on Chrome. But off course the <li> is not clickable than.

Comment: Don't really make sense. Take a look at this simple example and let me know what i'm missing http://jsfiddle.net/638hwLLq/

Comment: You are missing the underlaying select. That is causing a problem, clicking on the li is working fine. I add the underlaying div here: http://jsfiddle.net/638hwLLq/4/

Comment: Can you please help us with fixing the problem?

Comment: This will be almost impossible to debug without seeing the actually issue, by default it should work...Is this site live or can you update the jsfiddle with the html? Try http://jsfiddle.net/638hwLLq/5/

Comment: Tried that, but still the same problem in Chrome. Yes you can check it live. Can I mail you about this?

Comment: Or is it also possible to fix the problem without using onclick ref? Just by using <label>?

Comment: Can I sent you the file, so that you know the exact code?

Comment: Did you figure out the issue?

Comment: Yes problem solved. Used html and css :)